# hibernate query java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

In my hibernate query I have :

```
public void updateStudent(Student student) {


        String hql = "update Student set article =:null,id=2" 
                +"where article=:"+ student.getArticle();

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);

    }
```

Here I want to set student table's **article value= null and id =2**..but

```
every time an error is occurring:
 node to traverse cannot be null!
Caused by:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
```

my actual mysql query is:

```
UPDATE student
SET article='null', id=2
WHERE article='xyz';  here xyz=user.getArticle()
```

what am I doing wrong??

Comment: I think no need :null, just write null and with article in where clause the same.

Comment: can you give me the proper structure??

Comment: Here's how you pass parameters to a query: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-querying-executing-parameters. Everything is much simpler when you read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As @JBNizet mentions in the comment, you need to consult the documentation. But you need something like this to set your parameter.

```
public void updateStudent(Student student) {
    String hql = "update Student set article = null, id = 2" 
        + " where article = :article";

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery(hql)
        .setParameter("article", student.getArticle()) ... etc

}
```

P.S. I cannot understand why you are setting the id of your Student when you appear to be deleting an article value.